# Bluetooth discoverability

Tags: hardware, dell, bluetooth

Hi my bluetooth is present in hardware and I can turn it on in settings
but for some reason it is not enabled and I cannot turn on visability (discoverability).How can I fix this in a dell inspiron mini? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bluetooth Manager. Quite number of option and let you send and received file. Good for smart phone transfer. Been using since Ubuntu 12.10.

Get it Here [Blueman](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/blueman/)

[image]

Hope it help.