# Bluetooth indicator disappears on turning off bluetooth

Tags: indicator, bluetooth

Everytime I turn off my bluetooth, the indicator icon in the system tray disappears, as opposed to just greying out as expected. Next time I need to go to the settings select bluetooth to turn it on, which makes the indicator to reappear.

Is there anyway I can make the indicator icon not disappear but stay greyed out when not in use?

Comment: You can try this solution [Blueman](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293277/bluetooth-discoverability/293423#293423). Hope it help.

Comment: I had used Blueman back in 12.10. But didnt like the fact that it just created another bluetooth indicator apart from the one present by default. So when bluetooth is on, I would have two bluetooth icons in the system tray

Comment: To charlie, about blueman: it is possible to get rid of the extra bluetooth icon in the panel (disabling blueman's, leaving only the default icon). Instructions [here](http://krazyabouttechnology.blogspot.fi/2013/05/solution-bluetooth-not-working-after_3.html).

Comment: Bug report: [#1126108](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-bluetooth/+bug/1126108)

Comment: Did you try the solution provided and selected below? Let me know if that fixes it? I am trying to get it to be included in upstream upcoming versions, but dont know what I need to do for that...

Comment: It does work, however this is an offtopic question for AU as it is a known bug and the question will no longer be relevant once fixed.

Comment: There was a bug report [#1285951](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-bluetooth/+bug/1285951) where it was concluded that this was by design: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bluetooth#Indicator_and_menu. I think the design should be changed and I have stated my reasons in the bug report (which is currently marked as invalid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Grzegorz for the nudge in the right direction.

I found the below bazaar fork there. Its pending review but seems to be working for most:
https://code.launchpad.net/~robert-ancell/indicator-bluetooth/dont-hide-on-rfkill

---

**UPDATE:**

Installation instructions are at:

[How do I install a bazaar fork in 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296317/how-do-i-install-a-bazaar-fork-in-13-10)

**The summary of commands to use:**

```
sudo apt-get install bzr build-essential 
sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-bluetooth  
bzr branch lp:~robert-ancell/indicator-bluetooth/dont-hide-on-rfkill  
cd dont-hide-on-rfkill  
dpkg-buildpackage  
cd  
sudo dpkg -i indicator-bluetooth_0.0.6daily13.02.19-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Restart system

Comment: Very good research.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't make bluetooth activator to grey out if not active in Ubuntu 13.04.

Check the sources of [indicator-bluetooth](https://launchpad.net/indicator-bluetooth) at Launchpad.