# How do I install a bazaar fork in 13.10?

Tags: installation, 13.10, bazaar

I found a Bazaar fork promising a solution to one of my issues here:
[Bluetooth indicator disappears on turning off bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293360/bluetooth-indicator-disappears-on-turning-off-bluetooth/294149#294149)

Problem is, I followed their instructions, and all it did was download the code to a local folder in my $user home.

Where do I go on from here? How do I install the code so that I can start getting the benefits promised by the solution?

Comment: You can build Debian packages using **builddeb**: http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/builddeb-plugin.html#builddeb

Comment: Please transfer the comment to an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Install the pre-requisites:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr build-essential
```

And install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-bluetooth
```

### Branch the fork from Launchpad:

```
bzr branch lp:~robert-ancell/indicator-bluetooth/dont-hide-on-rfkill
```

Jump to the directory:

```
cd dont-hide-on-rfkill
```

### Install:

Now you have two options:

#### Compile from source

Run:

```
./configure  
make   
sudo make install
```

#### Install from compiled .deb

If you would rather install from a .deb run:

```
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Then:

```
cd
```

and

```
sudo dpkg -i indicator-bluetooth_0.0.6daily13.02.19-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, the first step gives me error:    `Package bazaar is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bazaar' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: @charlie Does `sudo apt-get update` complete successfully?

Comment: @charlie I just realized I named the package wrong. It should be `bzr` not `bazaar`. I have edited the answer to fix that. Please try again :)

Comment: Thanks @Seth. It completed all right, but is there anyway I can check to see if its installed okay. The most obvious method of turning on my bluetooth and checking is unavailable due to http://askubuntu.com/questions/364661/bluetooth-issues-after-saucy-upgrade . See if you can help me on that one. :) Thanks again.

Comment: A simple restart later, I was able to achieve the target. The bluetooth icon stays in the notification area...greyed when off, and activated when on. Thanks Seth!