# Missing Bluetooth indicator

Tags: bluetooth

I upgraded from Raring to Saucy, and now my bluetooth is giving me problems.

First, even though I have a bluetooth inbuilt in my laptop, which I prefer to keep off unless I am using it, there is no greyed out bluetooth icon in the notification area. This was present in Quantal, but was missing in Raring too. I was hoping to get this fixed in Saucy. Seems otherwise.

Secondly, and more importantly, in saucy when I am turning on my bluetooth, it immediately (or within seconds) turns off automatically, without giving me any time to even make the device visible.