# Ubuntu 13.10 laptop bluetooth not working properly

Tags: wireless, 13.10, bluetooth, speakers

I have an issue with bluetooth on Ubuntu 13.10 and I have no idea where to start looking. I finally gave a `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i bluetooth` and this is what I got (after a `sudo service bluetooth restart`):

```
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[764]: Terminating
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[764]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[764]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[764]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[764]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[764]: Stopping SDP server
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[764]: Exit
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Starting SDP server
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Failed to init time plugin
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Failed to init alert plugin
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: input-headset driver probe failed for device 7C:61:93:D4:A5:8F
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Adapter /org/bluez/3231/hci0 has been enabled
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: hci0: Get Connections (0x0015) failed: Not Powered (0x0f)
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Oct 25 19:30:02 razvan-asus bluetoothd[3231]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

As I never worked with the bluetooth before (now I have some wireless speakers) I don't know how to diagnose the problem. Have any of you encountered this? or is just me?

EDIT:

I should add, the laptop I'm using is ASUS U31S

EDIT2:

Today I tried searching for a new device (a mouse) with the bluetooth "set up new device" and it worked. And after pairing I could access the speakers too. Prior to this `hcitool dev` would give nothing now I have:

```
Devices:
        hci0    74:2F:68:69:BD:AD
```

So... as far as I can detect, prior to pairing hci0 was down and after the search and successful pairing the device turned on and now the other connections work too... Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this helps:**

I suspect your bluetooth not working on 13.10 can be attributed to a bug in the latest kernel.

It can be fixed by installing a bazaar fork below:

https://code.launchpad.net/~robert-ancell/indicator-bluetooth/dont-hide-on-rfkill

Installation instructions can be found at:

[How do I install a bazaar fork in 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296317/how-do-i-install-a-bazaar-fork-in-13-10)

The summary of commands to use:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr build-essential 
sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-bluetooth  
bzr branch lp:~robert-ancell/indicator-bluetooth/dont-hide-on-rfkill  
cd dont-hide-on-rfkill  
dpkg-buildpackage  
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i indicator-bluetooth_0.0.6daily13.02.19-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Restart the system.

Details are at [Missing Bluetooth indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364661/bluetooth-issues-after-saucy-upgrade/366604#366604)

Comment: I'll try it and let you know what I get. Thanks.

Comment: did try the above and got some ``Unmet build dependencies: libdbusmenu-gtk3-dev libgnome-bluetooth-dev libido3-0.1-dev libindicator3-dev valac-0.18`` so I'll just wait for the update. Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f`    
This would install any dependencies that your previous installs missed

Comment: Unfortunately it seems it's not that simple. ``sudo apt-get install -f`` doesn't seem to do anything about it. Anyhow, thanks for trying.