# Bluetooth device paired and connected (no sound)

Tags: sound, 13.10, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I've got a Bluetooth headset which works great in both Windows 8 and Android 4.2 however on Ubuntu (13.10) it just doesn't seem to work. I installed Blueman, it paired and connected successfully when I tried Audio sink but it still doesn't show up in my Sound Settings nor PulseAudio which I installed and tried. All there is in my Sound Settings is "Analog Output". I tried several fix like changing and adding things in /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf without any success. I've restarted the bluetooth service several times in the process as well.

Let me know if you need more information from me and my system.

Kind regards,
Michael.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm with the same [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370254/bluetooth-issues-ubuntu-13-10), after pair the headset, I'm using the `pulseaudio -k` command, then the device shows up in the Sound Settings and it works.

It's not a good solution, but it was what I got until now.

Comment: I see I'm not the only one with that specific issue. I'll give you the answer for leading me towards the right path and I'll stay up to date in your question instead. Thanks

Comment: LOL don't say it's not good. It just kills pulseaudio which starts itself up again. that's a very nice and easy solution :D

Comment: That worked for me, but afterwards Hangouts doesn't recognize my other headset

Comment: On my 16.04 this tip didn't work... :-(

Comment: Info:  `-k | --kill               Kill  an  already  running PulseAudio daemon of the calling user               (Equivalent to sending a SIGTERM). `

Answer (score 19):

I'm on Ubuntu gnome 16.04. Solution is to enable auto-detection, pair the headset again and select it in the list of output audio devices.

1. Change `#AutoEnable=false` to `AutoEnable=true` in the  `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` (notice new line is un-commented)
2. Unpair the headset
3. Restart the bluetooth service `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`
4. Pair your headset again and connect it
5. Go to sound settings. From the output device tab you should now see the headset listed along with other output device like internal speakers
6. Choose it as the sound output device.

Comment: Now I have no bluetooth devices at all...

Comment: when I did that I couldn't pair the device at all anymore. "failed to add device" + some ubuntu internal error

Comment: These steps worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04, using the SPEEDLINK Vias Nano dongle. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Running this on Ubuntu 18.04 fixed bluetooth not able to connect

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me.

There's an option in `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` 
called `AutoConnect=true`. Make sure this is **not** commented (i.e. no hashes)
(change `#AutoConnect=true` to `AutoConnect=true`)

This will make pulseaudio recognize the device.

**Note**: For Ubuntu 14 and up, the file is called `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`.

Comment: I think this worked for me. At least I can select the device now. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! After changing this option I had to remove the device from the Bluetooth menu and re-pair it, after it appeared!

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu  15.10 Gnome and for me `AutoEnable=true`  in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and I've found a solution that works perfectly here:

https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp

---

On ubuntu user is gdm and not Debian-gdm, here are the exact instructions:

> In order to prevent GDM from capturing the A2DP sink on session start,
>   edit **/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/client.conf** (or create it, if it
>   doesn't exist):
>
> ```
> autospawn = no
> daemon-binary = /bin/true
> ```
>
> After that you have to grant access to this file to **gdm** user:
>
> `$ chown gdm:gdm /var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/client.conf`
>
> In order to auto-connect a2dp for some devices, add this to
>   **/etc/pulse/default.pa**:
>
> `load-module module-switch-on-connect`
>
> Reboot.
>
> Now the sound device (bluetooth headset) should be accessible through
>   pavucontrol and standard audio device manager.

Answer (score 5):

i've got the same issue on Lubuntu 13.10 with blueman and an wireless speaker adapter. For me the following fixed it:

Insert `load-module module-switch-on-connect` in the /etc/pulse/default.pa

Command `pulseaudio -k`

Command `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

This module isn't loaded automatically, you have to load it manually. 
I didn't find a more convenient way.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 is to restart the bluetooth service, then reconnect the speaker:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

This seems to happen to me whenever I wake the computer from suspend.

Answer (score 2):

This also still happens in 20.04 ubuntu wayland especially once I come out of suspend.

I used  Eduardo's solution up there and it did not work. It just that added 2 more options to my  settings > Sound > Output Device Options, But still the Bluetooth device was not included as an option.

Additionally restarting the bluetooth service did it for me.

```
pulseaudio -k

sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Its not clean but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
mkdir -p ~gdm/.config/systemd/user
ln -s /dev/null ~gdm/.config/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket
```

Step 2: REMOVE the paired Bluetooth device
[Remove device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh5qj.png)

Step 3: PAIR it again

**This worked for me.**