# bluetooth headset connected and disabled

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have my bluetooth headset that used to work on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Now it is still connecting well to my computer but sound isnt working. as you can see on bluetooth config, I have a red cross 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq3i9.jpg) that might say it is disabled.
I tried to disconnect / reconnect, I tried everything written [on this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239209/no-sound-from-bluetooth-headset-but-its-detected) and [this one too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372071/bluetooth-device-paired-and-connected-no-sound/372111#372111).
PavuControl is installed and device is well displayed in list of output in the control.
I tried the python script, to kill pulseaudio, to set AutoEnable to true, unpaired device several times... nothing works.

I am at one point that I consider updating my ubuntu to 17 if it solves my issue. Any tips ?