# Ubuntu 13.10 bluetooth is not working

Tags: indicator, bluetooth

Blue-tooth is not working it is giving error like GDbus erro...

One solution to this i found is to install Blueman from app centre, but then I’ve two blue-tooth icons on indicator, i tried to remove the default blue-tooth but i can't, after removing is still shows up there.

Comment: try using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What is your question now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, here is how i fixed it.
Blueman somehow fixes the default bluetooth manager (`bluez`), but u will have two bluetooth icons
Blueman has a plugin named `AppIndicator` that allows it to show in the system tray.
So all you need to do is remove the plugin's files (to hide blueman's tray icon) & use the default bluetooth manager (`bluez`) to transfer files:

```
sudo rm '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/AppIndicator.pyc'  
sudo rm '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/AppIndicator.py'
```

Then restart/logout to see the results.

### I hope this helps

Comment: Man it worked but i did one more mistake...

I removed blueman from start up applications..

How to add that back.

Comment: run `startup applications` from dash, and check Blueman-applet, if it's not listed, just add it by clicking on `add` (Name : `Blueman Applet`,Command : `blueman-applet`)

Comment: Thax buddy for the help.

It's good now, working like charm.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your bluetooth not working on 13.10 can be attributed to a bug in the latest kernel.

It can be fixed by installing a bazaar fork below:

https://code.launchpad.net/~robert-ancell/indicator-bluetooth/dont-hide-on-rfkill

Installation instructions are at:

[How do I install a bazaar fork in 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296317/how-do-i-install-a-bazaar-fork-in-13-10)

The summary of commands to use:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr build-essential 
sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-bluetooth  
bzr branch lp:~robert-ancell/indicator-bluetooth/dont-hide-on-rfkill  
cd dont-hide-on-rfkill  
dpkg-buildpackage  
cd  
sudo dpkg -i indicator-bluetooth_0.0.6daily13.02.19-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Restart the system.

Details are at [Missing Bluetooth indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364661/bluetooth-issues-after-saucy-upgrade/366604#366604)