# bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: bluetooth

I upgrated ubuntu  from 13.4 to 13.10 and my bluetooth stopped working. When I open bluetooth I'm able to put it ON but the visibility doesn't show anything and didn't detect any device.

when I: `dmesg | grep Blue`

```
[    2.046249] usb 3-1: Product: Bluetooth V2.0 Dongle
[    2.046252] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Bluetooth v2.0
[   15.255710] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   15.255748] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.255759] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.255765] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.255776] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   20.110379] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.110386] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   20.110400] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.120635] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.120656] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.120660] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

when I digit: `lsusb`

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:2300 Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0e6a:6001 Megawin Technology Co., Ltd GEMBIRD Flexible keyboard KB-109F-B-DE
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13ee:0001 MosArt 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

when I: `hciconfig -a`

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1B:10:00:2A:EC  ACL MTU: 1017:8  SCO MTU: 64:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:457 acl:0 sco:0 events:16 errors:0
    TX bytes:68 acl:0 sco:0 commands:16 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8d 0xfe 0x9b 0xf9 0x00 0x80
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

when I digit: `rfkill list`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

when I digit: `sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

```
[General]

# List of plugins that should not be loaded on bluetoothd startup
#DisablePlugins = network,input

# Default adaper name
# %h - substituted for hostname
# %d - substituted for adapter id
Name = %h-%d

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
# considered.
Class = 0x000100

# How long to stay in discoverable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 180, i.e. 3 minutes.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay discoverable forever
DiscoverableTimeout = 0

# How long to stay in pairable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 0.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay pairable forever
PairableTimeout = 0

# Use some other page timeout than the controller default one
# which is 16384 (10 seconds).
PageTimeout = 8192

# Automatic connection for bonded devices driven by platform/user events.
# If a platform plugin uses this mechanism, automatic connections will be
# enabled during the interval defined below. Initially, this feature
# intends to be used to establish connections to ATT channels.
AutoConnectTimeout = 60

# What value should be assumed for the adapter Powered property when
# SetProperty(Powered, ...) hasn't been called yet. Defaults to true
InitiallyPowered = true

# Remember the previously stored Powered state when initializing adapters
RememberPowered = false

# Use vendor id source (assigner), vendor, product and version information for
# DID profile support. The values are separated by ":" and assigner, VID, PID
# and version.
# Possible vendor id source values: bluetooth, usb (defaults to usb)
#DeviceID = bluetooth:1234:5678:abcd

# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. This option is really only needed for qualification since the BITE tester
# doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases (though there could in
# theory be other useful purposes for this too). Defaults to true.
ReverseServiceDiscovery = true

# Enable name resolving after inquiry. Set it to 'false' if you don't need
# remote devices name and want shorter discovery cycle. Defaults to 'true'.
NameResolving = true

# Enable runtime persistency of debug link keys. Default is false which
# makes debug link keys valid only for the duration of the connection
# that they were created for.
DebugKeys = false

# Enable the GATT functionality. Default is false
EnableGatt = false
```

When I digit: uname -a

```
Linux casa-desktop 3.11.0-13-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 07:38:26 UTC 2013     x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I digit: lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
parport_pc             32701  0 
rfcomm                 69070  4 
bnep                   19564  2 
ppdev                  17671  0 
ip6t_REJECT            12910  1 
xt_hl                  12521  6 
ip6t_rt                13507  3 
nf_conntrack_ipv6      18938  9 
nf_defrag_ipv6         34616  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
ipt_REJECT             12541  1 
xt_LOG                 17718  8 
xt_limit               12711  11 
xt_tcpudp              12884  32 
xt_addrtype            12635  4 
nf_conntrack_ipv4      15012  9 
nf_defrag_ipv4         12729  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           12760  18 
ip6table_filter        12815  1 
ip6_tables             27025  1 ip6table_filter
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    12665  0 
nf_conntrack_broadcast    12589  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_nat_ftp             12741  0 
nf_nat                 26653  1 nf_nat_ftp
kvm_amd                59958  0 
nf_conntrack_ftp       18608  1 nf_nat_ftp
kvm                   431315  1 kvm_amd
nf_conntrack           91736  8   nf_nat_ftp,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_nat,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
iptable_filter         12810  1 
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ip_tables              27239  1 iptable_filter
snd_hda_codec_realtek    55704  1 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55624  0 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41117  1 
x_tables               34059  13 ip6table_filter,xt_hl,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,xt_limit,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,iptable_filter,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,ip6_tables,xt_addrtype,ip6t_REJECT
lrw                    13257  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_intel          48171  5 
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
joydev                 17377  0 
cryptd                 20329  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_hda_codec         188738  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
arc4                   12608  2 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
rt2800pci              18690  0 
snd_pcm               102033  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
radeon               1402449  3 
rt2800lib              79963  1 rt2800pci
btusb                  28267  0 
rt2x00pci              13287  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             13603  1 rt2800pci
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
rt2x00lib              55238  4 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2x00mmio
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
mac80211              596969  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
ttm                    83995  1 radeon
snd_rawmidi            30095  1 snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              479757  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
drm_kms_helper         52651  1 radeon
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             371880  12 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
microcode              23518  0 
eeprom_93cx6           13344  1 rt2800pci
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
crc_ccitt              12707  1 rt2800lib
snd_timer              29433  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69141  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
psmouse                97626  0 
drm                   296739  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
k10temp                13126  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
serio_raw              13413  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 radeon
i2c_piix4              22106  0 
video                  19318  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 53014  0 
hid                   105818  2 hid_generic,usbhid
pata_acpi              13038  0 
usb_storage            62062  1 
r8169                  67341  0 
sdhci_pci              18985  0 
sdhci                  42630  1 sdhci_pci
mii                    13934  1 r8169
pata_atiixp            13242  0 
ohci_pci               13561  0 
ahci                   25819  2 
libahci                31898  1 ahci
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install Blueman, here is how:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

after installation logout/re-login and bluetooth should be working fine.
if you notice two bluetooth icons on the taskbar, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/370361/132044) is how to fix it

Comment: I installed Blueman as you said but it still not works. On the taskbar there is only an icon and if I ask to set up new devices it say there is not any device. Also there's not chance to put the visibiblity on ON

Comment: I've blueman adapter 1.23

Comment: Where you able to fix it? I'm having the same problem