# Bluetooth not working - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I'm trying to sync my laptop with my bluetooth headphones.
The thing is that Ubuntu doesn't detect any device at all.

I've googled a little, tried some possible solutions. Like theese:

[Bluetooth not working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490346/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)
[Ubuntu 13.10 bluetooth is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370340/ubuntu-13-10-bluetooth-is-not-working)

But still not detecting any device.

Any ideas?

---

```
lsusb && lspci -nnk | grep -iA2
```

returns...

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3f6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0480:a00c Toshiba America Info. Systems, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Edit the question to add the results from this terminal command `lsusb && lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Don't know how, but it works now

Comment: Please add the info, because after the next power cycle it might not work due to a bug.  It isn't going to harm your hardware but it might make you pull your hair out

Answer (score 0):

Since the bluetooth adapter is an Atheros AR3012 it might suffer from a bug that will cause it to sometimes fail to load firmware during a cold boot.  A workaround that has worked for me is to blacklist ath3k with `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf` and then you can use terminal after booting to load ath3k with `sudo modprobe ath3k` or you can `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and add `modprobe ath3k` above the last line that has to be exit 0, save, exit gedit, and reboot