# Missing bluetooth applet on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, applet

I once messed up with `rfkill` command, which cause my bluetooth applet to disappear. Re-enable from system setting doesn't seem to work, it will stay disappear.

This question is similar to [Bluetooth indicator disappears on turning off bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293360/bluetooth-indicator-disappears-on-turning-off-bluetooth), but this workaround appear to be worked for 13.04 user only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just solved this issue by reinstalling `blueman` (bluetooth manager) and some `rfkill` tweak, now the bluetooth applet should be reappear:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall blueman
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this on 18.04 running Unity.
What fixed it for me was to start Unity Tweak tool, if you don't have it, in a terminal do:

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

Start it, go to **Unity - Launcher** (in overview).

Then go to the **Panel** tab, it should be under **Indicators**.
Check the checkbox or press **Restore defaults**, that did it for me.